# Wxpython: wxPyGridTableBase Appending Full Rows of Data

Tags: python, datagrid, wxpython

I'm trying to use wxPyGridTableBase to set up a record viewer in Wxpython, I'm wanting to pull records from a database that is an arbitrary amount of rows. Is there a way or an already existing method that will allow me to append rows to the grid (just like adding records to a dataTable?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPyGridTableBase#Table_Size.2BAC8-Shape_Reconfiguration:

```
bool InsertRows(size_t pos = 0, size_t numRows = 1)
bool AppendRows(size_t numRows = 1)
```